# Multiple-types decoder in golang

Tags: xml-parsing, go

I have an XML document. Some fields have custom format. Example:

```
<document>
  <title>hello world</title>
  <lines>
   line 1
   line 2
   line 3
  </lines>
</document>
```

I want to import it into structure like:

```
type Document struct {
    Title  string   `xml:"title"`
    Lines  []string `xml:"lines"`
}
```

Is there some way how to implement custom decoder, which will split lines string into array of lines (`["line 1", "line 2", "line 3"]`)?

Its possible to make Lines field a string type and make split after xml import, but it doesn't seems to be very elegant solution. Is there any way i can define custom decoder for line spliting and combine it with xml decoder?

Comment: Not according to the rules: http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal. It will map it always to a string. It also you make no sense for the XML Parser to touch those lines a all, since it's not part of the XML structure. Why not break the lines by yourself by adding a Method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining a new type that conforms to the `xml.Unmarshaler` interface.  So rather than making `Lines` a `[]string`, declare a new type with an appropriate `UnmarshalXML` method.  For instance:

```
type Lines []string

func (l *Lines) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    var content string
    if err := d.DecodeElement(&content, &start); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *l = strings.Split(content, "\n")
    return nil
}
```

You can see a full example here: http://play.golang.org/p/3SBu3bOGjR

If you want to support encoding this type too, you can implement the `MarshalXML` method in a similar fashion (construct the string content you want and pass that to the encoder).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a spelled out example of what CSE is suggesting:

```
type Document struct {
    Title    string `xml:"title"`
    LineData string `xml:"lines"`
}

func (d *Document)Lines() []string {
    return strings.Split(d.LineData, '\n')
}
```

This is similar to what [net/http Request](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/request.go) does: read the data into a struct, and then provide accessors to interpret that struct.

If you really don't want to do that, then another approach that I have used is to create two structs. Read the raw data into the first and then use that to construct the second.

If you are planning on shipping this out as JSON or some other wire format, the second struct could just be a map.

```
func (d *Document) Map() map[string]interface{} {
    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    m["lines"] = strings.Split(d.LineData, '\n')
    m["title"] = d.Title
    return m
}
```