# Custom string translation while decoding XML in Golang

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing

I am decoding some XML which contains only string values and attributes. It also contains a few instances of `"&amp;amp;"`, which is unfortunate, and I'd like to decode that to just `"&"` rather than `"&amp;"`. I'm also going to do some more work with these string values in which I need the character `"|"` to never appear, and so I'd like to replace any `"|"` instance with `"%7C"`.

I could do these changes using `strings.Replace` after the decoding, but since the decoding is already doing similar work (after all it does translate `"&amp;"` to `"&"`) I'd like to do it at the same time.

The files I will be parsing are huge, so I'll be doing something similar to http://blog.davidsingleton.org/parsing-huge-xml-files-with-go/

Here is a short example xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tests>
    <test_content>X&amp;amp;Y is a dumb way to write XnY | also here's a pipe.</test_content>
    <test_attr>
      <test name="Normal" value="still normal" />
      <test name="X&amp;amp;Y" value="should be the same as X&amp;Y | XnY would have been easier." />
    </test_attr>
</tests>
```

And some Go code that does standard decoding and prints out the results:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type XMLTests struct {
    Content string     `xml:"test_content"`
    Tests   []*XMLTest `xml:"test_attr>test"`
}

type XMLTest struct {
    Name  string `xml:"name,attr"`
    Value string `xml:"value,attr"`
}

func main() {
    xmlFile, err := os.Open("test.xml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening file:", err)
        return
    }
    defer xmlFile.Close()

    var q XMLTests

    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile)

    // I tried this to no avail:
    // decoder.Entity = make(map[string]string)
    // decoder.Entity["|"] = "%7C"
    // decoder.Entity["&amp;amp;"] = "&"

    var inElement string
    for {
        t, _ := decoder.Token()
        if t == nil {
            break
        }
        switch se := t.(type) {
        case xml.StartElement:
            inElement = se.Name.Local
            if inElement == "tests" {
                decoder.DecodeElement(&q, &se)
            }
        default:
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(q.Content)
    for _, t := range q.Tests {
        fmt.Printf("\t%s\t\t%s\n", t.Name, t.Value)
    }
}
```

How do I modify this code to get what I want? ie: **How does one customize the decoder?**

I looked at the docs, specifically https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder and tried playing with the Entity map, but I was unable to make any progress.

**Edit:**

Based on the comments, I've followed the example from [Multiple-types decoder in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164455/multiple-types-decoder-in-golang) and added/changed the following to the above code:

```
type string2 string

type XMLTests struct {
    Content string2    `xml:"test_content"`
    Tests   []*XMLTest `xml:"test_attr>test"`
}

type XMLTest struct {
    Name  string2 `xml:"name,attr"`
    Value string2 `xml:"value,attr"`
}

func (s *string2) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    var content string
    if err := d.DecodeElement(&content, &start); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    content = strings.Replace(content, "|", "%7C", -1)
    content = strings.Replace(content, "&amp;", "&", -1)
    *s = string2(content)
    return nil
}
```

That works for the `test_content` but not for the attributes?

```
X&Y is a dumb way to write XnY %7C also here's a pipe.
    Normal      still normal
    X&amp;Y     should be the same as X&Y | XnY would have been easier.
```

Comment: You actually want to do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164455/multiple-types-decoder-in-golang where you provide an implementation of `UnmarshalXML` although I don't personally think it's any better than just calling some function like `type.Sanatize()` after the fact. I personally would take the latter because it's less obfuscated. I see custom `Unmarshal` implementations a lot like operator overloading, more confusion and work than they're worth.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Both options are quite dissatisfying. I mean the existing decoder is already changing "&amp;" to "&" along with other standard xml escapes, is it really so hard-coded that I cannot just tag along there? I'm not trying to actually break the XML rules like in the other question.

Comment: I mean that's what implementing `UnmarshalXML` does... You can just decode everything, run string replace and then call the regular `Unmarshal`, it's not like you have to do any of the hard work. I'm not terribly privy to xml's spec but afaik `|` has no special designation so why would you expect to be able to have it treated like an escape character? Yes I would expect that list of special character to be hard coded and unexported, why would it not be?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal You make a fair point. Looks like either way I'm not going to get anything for free, unfortunately. Thanks.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Please see my edit. Seems that I'm only 50% of the way there using the example from the other question.

Comment: Yeah that only decodes the first element. I'm looking into the docs to try and figure out how to iterate over all elements or decode everything at one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with attributes, you can use the [`UnmarshalerAttr`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#UnmarshalerAttr) interface with the `UnmarshalXMLAttr` method. Your example then becomes:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type string2 string

type XMLTests struct {
    Content string2    `xml:"test_content"`
    Tests   []*XMLTest `xml:"test_attr>test"`
}

type XMLTest struct {
    Name  string2 `xml:"name,attr"`
    Value string2 `xml:"value,attr"`
}

func decode(s string) string2 {
    s = strings.Replace(s, "|", "%7C", -1)
    s = strings.Replace(s, "&amp;", "&", -1)
    return string2(s)
}

func (s *string2) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    var content string
    if err := d.DecodeElement(&content, &start); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *s = decode(content)
    return nil
}

func (s *string2) UnmarshalXMLAttr(attr xml.Attr) error {
    *s = decode(attr.Value)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    xmlData := `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tests>
    <test_content>X&amp;amp;Y is a dumb way to write XnY | also here's a pipe.</test_content>
    <test_attr>
      <test name="Normal" value="still normal" />
      <test name="X&amp;amp;Y" value="should be the same as X&amp;Y | XnY would have been easier." />
    </test_attr>
</tests>`
    xmlFile := strings.NewReader(xmlData)

    var q XMLTests

    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile)
    decoder.Decode(&q)

    fmt.Println(q.Content)
    for _, t := range q.Tests {
        fmt.Printf("\t%s\t\t%s\n", t.Name, t.Value)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
X&Y is a dumb way to write XnY %7C also here's a pipe.
    Normal      still normal
    X&Y     should be the same as X&Y %7C XnY would have been easier.
```

(You can test this in the [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XdfuZTEeg-).)

So if using `string2` everywhere is suitable for you, this should do the trick.

(*edit*: simpler code, without using `DecodeElement` and a type switch...)